# How do I delete a defined schema from Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Node.js and mongoose to interface with MongoDB. My current implementation dynamically creates Mongoose schemas during runtime. These schemas are then used to create objects which get stored in their respective collections in MongoDB. At some point, a delete function (express endpoint) might get called which then deletes one or more of these collections and it's schema reference from code (sets it to undefined). However, when I go about re-creating one of these schemas, mongoose complains that the old one already exists!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this below make me understand if there will be the same problam:

```
mongoose.connection.collections['yourCollectionName'].drop( function(err) {
    console.log('collection dropped');
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error as before. I've pasted the error in paste bin at [link](http://pastebin.com/skUyt9zG)